# Windows Server 2003 - Can't Activate. Message number: 32777

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-activation

I am building a test lab with version of Windows Server 2003 Enterprise in my Hyper-V environment. This Windows Server 2003 64 bit was downloaded from MSDN. This is needed to install a specific version of older Microsoft product.

Can someone help me understand how I can activate Windows 2003 64 bit, SP1 (from MSDN)? [I have tried every step from this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/message-number-32777#workaround-3-turn-off-certificate-revocation-in-internet-explorer) except an activation via the phone.

I am getting this error message:

> Unable to establish a connection with the activation server. Please
> check your network settings and confirm that you are able to connect
> to the Internet, then try again.

> Message number: 32777

**System Properties**

[image]

**When activating Windows Server 2003**

[image]

**Internet is configured and working**
[image]

**What I tried + More info**

- Firewall termporarily disabled.
- I do not have any proxies used.
- Internet Explorer Echanced Security Configuration is turned off
- I have turned offcertificate revocation in Internet Explorer. [As suggested here.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/message-number-32777#workaround-3-turn-off-certificate-revocation-in-internet-explorer)

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You should try to activate your installation by phone.  You can also provide your Setuplog.txt in order to diagnose the issue.  If it does not already exist [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-log-files-and-event-logs) probably applies.  There are multiple reasons for 32777 which means you have to provide the information to diagnose the reason other than the one specified in the article.   I strongly suggest just activating by phone.

Comment: Thank you. I just called the toll-free number and was able to activate the instance sucessfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was suggested by someone, the automated activations might not be supported any longer. As a result, I ended up calling the toll-free number and was able to successfully activate Windows Server 2003.

[image]

Background: Even though it's an old and unsupported OS, I still need it to setup an old version of another unsupported MS product on top of it.